# HTML Form Input Image Storing In SQLite Database

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I have an HTML form with a file input named "**img**" which only supports JPEG file types through it's browse window.

I have a SQLite 3 **database.db** file. It has a **user** table with an **image** column set to **BLOB** type.

How can I store the selected image from the HTML form into the SQLite database?

I'm looking for a simple solution using **PHP** language as it would be somewhat easy for me to understand and I'm already using it to **INSERT** other plain text data into the database.

Comment: There are many, many examples of doing this on SO and the web in general. It would be an idea to investigate them, try to implement for yourself and if you run into issues ask for assistance rather than expect the solution to be neatly placed in front of you with a bow on top

Comment: What made you think that actual image data belonged into the database to begin with? In most cases, that should reside in the file system.

Comment: @RamRaider I have already tried and that's why I have posted. The normal INSERT query just stored the image file name that I have selected through the file input in the database. I don't understand similar issues posted here as it's too advanced for me. I'm asking for the bare minimum code as I have highlighted and pointed out in the question here.

Comment: @04FS So there's no way to store an image in SQLite database? I mean the actual image data should be stored in that image column.

Comment: Of course there are _ways_ - but you should question the _sense_ behind doing that first. The file system is perfectly capable of storing image files, and in combination with the web server’s default mechanisms it is also terribly easy to get them delivered to the website visitors - you get all of that “build-in” already, at no extra cost - whereas with storing images in the database, you would have to implement the mechanism to fetch and deliver them via HTTP yourself. So you should have a _good_ reason for wanting to go this route in the first place.

Comment: @04FS My idea was to INSERT the image data in database so that I can SELECT it from the database using the INSERT/SELECT query code that I already have since I already doing this for the plain text inputs in the form. I don't know if that's how it works. Would it require much work to convert the image BLOB data when it needs to be displayed back as the actual image?

Comment: _“since I already doing this for the plain text inputs in the form”_ - I said you should have a _good_ reason for storing binary image data into the database - not just _any_ arbitrary reason ;-) Store the file name (and path, if necessary) into the database, not the actual image data. Then you just output that as the `src` of an `img` element, and all the rest happens automatically.

Comment: @04FS Seems that's what I have to do now. Thanks.